# Limit to unique ID a CASE with multiple clauses

Tags: oracle, join, subquery, case, union-all

Based on the input of the two comments on my original post, I made a change and created a version of the script below.  Everything below is called T13 and left joins with another table. And it worked.  Maybe there was a more efficient way to do it, but it worked.  Then, the only thing that I did was add the "UNION ALL" section.  Since then, I keep getting the following error:

ERROR:
ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual. *Action:
Error at Line: 143 Column: 27

I chase the error and just re-write the same code, and then it pops up again with a different line and column.

-

Below is the original post of what I was trying to do.

The script below is meant to give me a `yes` or `no` for every `AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID`. The problem is that the `medication_ID` might have additionally occurred outside my time constraints. The result is multiple `AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID` one of which is `yes` and the rest `no`. How can I have only one unique `AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID` with `yes` if it occurred in the listed time constraint, otherwise `no`. I thought about an approach to COUNT the lines of unique `AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID` that contained `yes` and then group on `AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID` but I couldn't wrap my head around it.

Any help out there?

```
SELECT T3.AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID, T3.AN_STOP_DATETIME, (T3.AN_STOP_DATETIME +.125),
CASE
  WHEN TOTAL_ADMIN_COUNT > 0 THEN 'YES'
  ELSE 'NO' END AS PONV
From (SELECT
  CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY.AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID,
  CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY.AN_STOP_DATETIME,
  CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY.AN_EPISODE_ID
    FROM CLARITY.OR_LOG
    INNER JOIN CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY
    ON CLARITY.OR_LOG.LOG_ID = CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY.LOG_ID
    INNER JOIN CLARITY.V_LOG_BASED
    ON CLARITY.OR_LOG.LOG_ID = CLARITY.V_LOG_BASED.LOG_ID
    INNER JOIN CLARITY.PATIENT
    ON CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY.AN_PAT_ID = CLARITY.PATIENT.PAT_ID
    WHERE CLARITY.OR_LOG.LOC_ID             IN (4060020, 4060021)
    and (CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY.AN_STOP_DATETIME - CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY.AN_START_DATETIME) *24*60 > 0
) T10

LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT  AN_EPISODE_ID,
        SUM(MedCount) AS TOTAL_ADMIN_COUNT
FROM (SELECT AN_EPISODE_ID, COUNT(ord.ORDER_MED_ID) as MedCount
      FROM F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY An
      inner join MAR_ADMIN_INFO Mar
      on An.AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID = Mar.MAR_ENC_CSN
      inner join ORDER_MED Ord
      on Mar.ORDER_MED_ID = Ord.ORDER_MED_ID
      inner join V_LOG_TIMING_EVENTS ORL
      on An.LOG_ID = ORL.LOG_ID
      where Ord.MEDICATION_ID IN (104661, 2787)
      and Mar.TAKEN_TIME > AN.AN_STOP_DATETIME -- ANESTHESIA STOP TIME
      and Mar.TAKEN_TIME < (AN.AN_STOP_DATETIME +.125) -- ANESTHESIA STOP TIME PLUS 3 HOURS
      group by An.AN_EPISODE_ID
      Union all
      select AN_EPISODE_ID, COUNT(ord2.ORDER_MED_ID) as MedCount
      from F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY An2
      inner join AN_HSB_LINK_INFO Link2
      on An2.AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID=Link2.AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID
      inner join MAR_ADMIN_INFO Mar2
      on Link2.AN_BILLING_CSN_ID = Mar2.MAR_ENC_CSN
      inner join ORDER_MED Ord2
      on Mar2.ORDER_MED_ID = Ord2.ORDER_MED_ID
      inner join V_LOG_TIMING_EVENTS ORL2
      on An2.LOG_ID = ORL2.LOG_ID
      where Ord2.MEDICATION_ID IN (104661, 2787)
      and Mar2.TAKEN_TIME > AN.AN_STOP_DATETIME -- ANESTHESIA STOP TIME
      and Mar2.TAKEN_TIME < (AN.AN_STOP_DATETIME +.125) -- Stop +3 HOURS
      Group by An2.AN_EPISODE_ID
) 
GROUP BY AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID
)T11
ON T10. AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID = T11. AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a `LOJ` on the same dataset using common table expressions. This is not tested, just an idea

```
WITH temp_calc AS ( your query... ) 
SELECT          t1.*, 
                CASE  WHEN t2.ponv_prophylaxis = 'yes' THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' 
                END AS new_ponv_prophylaxis 
FROM            temp_calc t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN temp_calc t2 
ON              t1.an_52_enc_csn_id= t2.an_52_enc_csn_id AND other joins...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the row_number analytic function to work out the first row and then set everything else to `'no'`:

```
select an_52_enc_csn_id,
       case when row_number() over (partition by an_52_enc_csn_id order by ponv_prophylaxis desc) = 1
                 then ponv_prophylaxis
            else 'no'
       end ponv_prophylaxis
from   (select rsum.an_52_enc_csn_id,
               case when om.medication_id in ( 104661, 104662 ) 
                           and mai.taken_time > vlte.patient_in_preprocedure_dttm 
                           and mai.taken_time < vlte.patient_out_room_dttm 
                         then 'yes' 
                    else 'no' 
               end as ponv_prophylaxis 
        from   clarity.or_log olg
               inner join clarity.f_an_record_summary rsum on olg.log_id = rsum.log_id 
               inner join clarity.v_log_based vlg on olg.log_id = vlg.log_id 
               left join clarity.mar_admin_info mai on rsum.an_52_enc_csn_id = mai.mar_enc_csn 
               inner join clarity.order_med om on mai.order_med_id = om.order_med_id 
               inner join clarity.v_log_timing_events vlte on rsum.log_id = vlte.log_id 
        where  olg.loc_id in ( 4060020, 4060021 ));
```

N.B. You'll note that I've used aliases for the tables; it makes it much easier to read as well as declutters the SQL statement, making it smaller!

Comment: I appreciate the input, but that didn't work.  Still had duplicate 52_enc rows with yes and no.

Comment: It would help if you could update your question to provide some sample output data that your query produces along with the result you want to achieve. That way, we ought to be able to help you better.